# Getting different answers for same problem on divergence and curl.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vectors, divergence-operator, curl

Given that $\vec{a}$ is a constant vector and $\vec{r}$ is a position vector.

We are asked to prove the following:
$$\nabla\times(\vec{a}\times\vec{r})=2\vec{a}$$
I tried two ways. Could prove it from one method but from another I am getting another result.

$$\rule{20cm}{0.4pt}$$

1st method(with correct result):

$$LHS=\nabla\times(\vec{a}\times\vec{r})$$
Let $\vec{a}=a_1\hat{i}+a_2\hat{j}+a_3\hat{k} \,\,$ and $\,\,\vec{r}=x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}+z\hat{k},$ where $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are constants and $x,y,z$ is any arbitrary point.

$$Simplifying\,\,\,\, (\vec{a}\times\vec{r})$$

$$=\begin{vmatrix}\hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k} \\ a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\ x & y & z\end{vmatrix}$$
$$=\hat{i}(a_2z-a_3y)+\hat{j}(a_3x-a_1z)+\hat{k}(a_1y-a_2x)$$

Now performing the curl operation on the simplified result we obtained.
$$=\nabla\times(simplified\,result)$$
$$=\begin{vmatrix}\hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} &\frac{\partial}{\partial y}  & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\ a_2z-a_3y & a_3x-a_1z & a_1y-a_2x\end{vmatrix}$$

$$=2a_1x\hat{i}+2a_2y\hat{j}+2a_3z\hat{k}$$
$$=2\vec{a}$$
$$=RHS$$
$$\rule{20cm}{0.4pt}$$
2nd method with incorrect result.

We know that $$\nabla\times(\vec{a}\times\vec{r})=2[(\nabla.\vec{r})\vec{a}-(\nabla.\vec{a})\vec{r}]$$

Solving RHS,

$$Also,\nabla.\vec{r}=3\,and\, \nabla.\vec{a}=0$$
$$=2[3\vec{a}-0\vec{r}]$$
$$=6\vec{a}$$
which is incorrect. Where did I make mistake in this method?

Comment: Check the curl identity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)#Identities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "vector calculus identity" you use in your second calculation is just false. You actually have
\begin{align*}
\nabla \times (\vec{a} \times \vec{r}) &= \vec{a}(\nabla \cdot \vec{r}) - \vec{r}(\nabla \cdot \vec{a}) + (\vec{r} \cdot \nabla)\vec{a} - (\vec{a} \cdot \nabla) \vec{r} \\
&= 
\vec{a}(\nabla \cdot \vec{r})  - (\vec{a} \cdot \nabla) \vec{r}.
\end{align*}
As you say, the first term on the RHS is then $3 \vec{a}$, but we need to calculate the other term. It is just the directional derivative of $\vec{r}$ in the direction of $\vec{a}$ multiplied by the magnitude of $\vec{a}$, so this is just $\vec{a}$. Thus
$$
\nabla \times (\vec{a} \times \vec{r}) = 3 \vec{a} - \vec{a} = 2 \vec{a},
$$
as desired.

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/71CHGVa9Hkt2U7Hk8  is the proof for identity I have used.

Comment: @AbbasMiya I can't see the image---you can just add it to your question.

Comment: But at any rate, the mistake must be there.

Comment: I am sorry for the link,  it is fine now, you can see the picture.

Comment: @AbbasMiya That "simplification" of the identity in red is *not correct*. The confusion seems to be that $\vec{a} \cdot \nabla$ does not equal $\nabla \cdot \vec{a}$, for example. Instead $\vec{a} \cdot \nabla$ is an *operator* which differentates in the $\vec{a}$ direction and then multiplies by the magnitude of $\vec{a}$. On the other hand, $\nabla \cdot \vec{a}$ is just a number (and in your case it is zero).

Comment: I got it, thank you. https://www.quora.com/Is-nabla-cdot-a-equal-to-a-cdot-nabla-in-vector-calculus found this as well.